# Having trouble with finding a limit for this sequence $a_n=\frac{n+1}{n}\ln(\sqrt{n})-\frac{1}{n^2}\sum^n_{k=1}\ln(k+n)^k$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, riemann-sum

We got this question as a bonus for our homework assignment and
I'm having trouble figuring out how to start to solve this limit. We need to find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n)$ for this sequence:

> $$a_n=\frac{n+1}{n}\ln(\sqrt{n})-\frac{1}{n^2}\sum^n_{k=1}\ln(k+n)^k$$

Can anyone give suggestions on how to solve this? (any help would be appreciated)

p.s. This was in the 'Riemann sums' section of our homework assignment

Comment: Hint: $$
\frac{1}{{n^2 }}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\log (k + n)^k }  = \frac{{\log n}}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{k}{n}}  + \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{k}{n}\log \left( {1 + \frac{k}{n}} \right)} 
$$ and $$
\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {f\left( {\frac{k}{n}} \right)}  \to \int_0^1 {f(x)dx} 
$$ if $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Comment: @Gary thank you king 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define
\begin{align}
g(n) = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum^n_{k=1}k\ln\left( k+n \right).
\end{align}
Since $f(x) = x \ln(x + n)$ is an increasing function, we find
\begin{align}
n^{-2}\int_{0}^{n}\mathrm{d} x~f(x) < ~& g(n) < n^{-2}\int_{1}^{n+1}\mathrm{d} x~f(x) \\
\frac{1+2\ln n}{4}<~&g(n) <  \frac{n^2 - 1}{2n^{2}}\ln(n+1) + \frac{n-2}{4n} + \frac{2n+1}{2n}\frac{\ln(2n+1)}{n}.
\end{align}
Therefore, we obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{\ln n}{2n} - \frac{1}{4}< a_{n} < \frac{n+1}{2n}\left(\ln n - \frac{n - 1}{n}\ln(n+1)\right) - \frac{n-2}{4n} + \frac{2n+1}{2n}\frac{\ln(2n+1)}{n}.
\end{align}
Since both LHS and RHS approach $-1/4$ in the limit of $n \to \infty$, we can conclude
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n} = -\frac{1}{4}.
$$